# Types are not assert correctly during generic initialization via constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm facing a little problem in TypeScript, and I'm not sure if it's me miss-typing something, or TypeScript that cannot assert correctly the types. Let me show all the code needed to reproduce the issue:

```
interface IRawFoo { type: string };

type FooConstructor = new (...args: any[]) => BaseFoo;

class BaseFoo { }
class Ext1Foo extends BaseFoo { }
class Ext2Foo extends BaseFoo { }

const FooConstructorMap = {
    "ext1": Ext1Foo,
    "ext2": Ext2Foo,
}

function getConstructor(rawFoo: IRawFoo): FooConstructor {
    return FooConstructorMap[rawFoo.type];
}

function getInstance(rawFoo: IRawFoo): BaseFoo {
    const fooConstructor = getConstructor(rawFoo);
    return initializeFoo(rawFoo, fooConstructor);
}

function initializeFoo<T extends FooConstructor>(rawFoo: IRawFoo, constructor: T): InstanceType<T> {
    const newFoo = new constructor();

    /* Doing stuff for each FOO instance. */

    return newFoo; // TS ERROR HERE
}

/* USAGE EXAMPLE .*/
const ext1RawFoo : IRawFoo = { type: "ext2" };
const ext1Foo = initializeFoo(ext1RawFoo, Ext1Foo); // <- In this example, ext1Foo is a "Ext1Foo".
```

Now, let me try to explain it quickly:

- I Have `BaseFoo` and n classes that extends it;
- The constructors of each n classes is mapped via an object;
- I must be able to call `getInstance` which returns a `BaseFoo`. Eventually, I will be able to use `instanceof()` to assert the specific type of the returned element;
- I must be able to call `initializeFoo` passing the constructor directly, and have the return type without any assertion;

The current code gives me this error in the `return` statement of `initializeFoo`:
`Type 'BaseFoo' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<T>'.ts(2322)`

Though, I'm not sure why, since the code I wrote make sense to me.
In `initializeFoo`, I'm asserting that `T` extends `FooConstructor`, thus `T` is an object having a constructor that returns an instance of `BaseFoo`.
Then, I'm also saying that `initializeFoo` returns an `InstanceType<T>`. Since instanciated `T` returns a `BaseFoo` due to `T extends FooConstructor`, I think the assertion that `InstanceType<T> extends BaseFoo` can be made.. But, TypeScript does not.

At this point, I don't know if I'm writing something wrong and there's a better way to write this, or TypeScript is not smart enough to make that assumption.

I know I could write the signature of `initializeFoo` like this:
`function initializeFoo<T extends FooConstructor>(rawFoo: IRawFoo, constructor: T): BaseFoo`

But then, when I would write this:
`const ext1Foo = initializeFoo(ext1RawFoo, Ext1Foo);`

`ext1Foo` type would be `BaseFoo` and not `Ext1Foo`.. Which I don't like.

Finally, I know I can fix this by writing:
`return newFoo as InstanceType<T>`

But using the `as`, it seems to me I'm cheating due to bad code wrote.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the tricky part here is what it means to have `T extends FooConstructor`. Since `FooConstructor` is defined as `new (...args: any[]) => BaseFoo`, something that extends `FooConstructor` is *also* a function that returns a `BaseFoo`; it simply may take more specific arguments, have more properties, etc. What you want is a "constructor that returns a type that extends `BaseFoo`", not a "constructor of a type that extends a constructor type that returns `BaseFoo`".

Here's how you can redefine your constructor type and initialize function to work as you intend:

```
type FooConstructor<T extends BaseFoo = BaseFoo> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

// ...

function initializeFoo<T extends BaseFoo>(rawFoo: IRawFoo, constructor: FooConstructor<T>): T {
    const newFoo = new constructor();

    /* Doing stuff for each FOO instance. */

    return newFoo;
}
```

Comment: I have to say: I did try that signature for `FooConstructor` (using the `extends BaseFoo = BaseFoo`), but I missed the new signature of `initialializeFoo`.. It seems I was still using `InstanceType<T>`, which gave me error. Anyways, thank you